# Determine Environment in Spring Boot based on Weblogic environment variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic, environment, spring-java-config

I am trying to determine the environment that the application is in but using the environment variable that Weblogic sets at startup via this line:

`-Denvironment=DEV`

I have a configuration class below:

```
package ie.gov.agriculture.cds;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${environment}")
    private String env;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

In the application.properties, if I define the property "environment", then it seems to work, but this is not what I want to achieve. 
It appears that I need to replace the PropertySource annotation value with something that will point to the weblogic server?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is that I was missing the property in my weblogic server configuration which is why it was not being picked up.

Inside the domains\%APPCODE%\bin folder of my weblogic server, in the setDomainEnv.cmd file, I included the environment property.

set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dssoautologin.appcode=%APPCODE% -Denvironment=DESKTOP

This can then be picked up by Spring using the `@Value("${environment}")` annotation.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

If it's an environment variable you can access doing:

```
String env = System.getProperty("environment");
```

Thus you don't need set it as property in your application.properties

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing with the below line. I see the `$` is missing in your code

```
@Value("${environment}")
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo, sorry. Edited now.